# CSS in email template not centering div children

Tags: html, css, pug

I have this email template in pug:

```
div(style={ display: 'flex', 'justify-content': 'center', 'flex-direction': 'row', 'text-align': 'center'})
            div.image_column
                a(href="#" target="_blank")
                    img.social_media_image(src= 'facebook.png' alt='Facebook')
            div.image_column
                a(href="#" target="_blank")
                    img.social_media_image(src= 'linkedin.png' alt='Linkedin')
            div.image_column
                a(href="#" target="_blank")
                    img.social_media_image(src= 'instagram.png' alt='Instagram')
            div.image_column
                a(href="#" target="_blank")
                    img.social_media_image(src= 'twitter.png' alt='Twitter')
```

locally the icons are perfectly showing in the center
here is an image
[image]

But in an email client like gmail the css attributes disappear. And when I inspect I see only these -> `style="display:flex;text-align:center"`

Does anyone have any idea why is that happening ? And does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail doesn't support all Flexbox properties. For instance, [`flex-direction`](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/flexbox/flex-direction/) is not supported. Email client support for CSS features is very different and more limited than browser support.

You don't need Flexbox to align inline elements like `<a>` to center. You could just write this instead:

```
div(style='text-align: center;')
  a(href="#" target="_blank")
    img.social_media_image(src='facebook.png', alt='Facebook')
  a(href="#" target="_blank")
    img.social_media_image(src='linkedin.png', alt='Linkedin')
  a(href="#" target="_blank")
    img.social_media_image(src='instagram.png', alt='Instagram')
  a(href="#" target="_blank")
    img.social_media_image(src='twitter.png', alt='Twitter')
```